# c# = pass class variable in a method

Tags: c#, object

Does anybody know if its possible to pass a class in a method (in c#)?

Or maybe provide some insight into how I might better solve/approach this problem as it could be a "can't see the forest from the trees" type of thing.

Basically, I have different types of objects (people, vehicles, locations and items) that I'm handling and I want to let the user add/edit/view/delete

these objects. To support this, I've created one form (which I'll call the "ObjecctSelect Form") that allows the user to select a specific object from a list of objects (I pass the "object type" into the form and the form then knows to create a list of these objects from which the user can select...such as a vehicle).  Once the user has selected an object, the ObjectSelect form then calls another form (which varies depending on the object type as I have a AEVD_Vehicle form, a AEVD Location form, etc) which will allow the user to add/edit/view/delete the selected object.

This actually works pretty well when I had the objects "well-defined" but now I might have the need for some "custom" objects and was hoping that I could pass in the add/edit/view/delete "custom object" form into my "ObjectSelect" form.  I know I can pass an instance of an class (and NOT the class itself) but I really don't have the constructor information until the object is selected...or whether the user has selected whether he wants to add, edit, view or delete the selected object.

BTW, Another reason I want to be able to pass into a form is that I've put the "objectSelect" form into a library which is being used by several applications which we're developing.  As it turns out, depending on the platform we're dealing with, the "AddEditDelete Object form" may require different manufacturer libraries to be referenced by it and I don't want to have my "library" reference all of these manufacturer libraries....plus these manufacturers handle things differently.  For instance, some of the add/edit/view/delete forms include barcode scanning and picture taking - with one manufacturer, I have to turn one off before doing the other whereas for another manufacturer, I don't need to do anything...

Does this make sense?  Or is there a different/better way I should be handling this?

Comment: Can you summarize what you need in pseudocode?

Answer (score 0):

I think where I'd start approaching a problem like this is by thinking about all the different things that you'd like to do with a specific type. From what you've listed so far, it sounds like for each type, you have a way to get the data and a way to edit an item with an associated form. So what it seems like it would make sense to do is take all the implementations around a specific type and put that into a common structure of some sort and then use that structure to do the work.

For example, suppose our two types of objects are ints and strings instead of vehicles, etc.
Then you could do something like this:

```
public interface IEditorForm
{
     void SetItemToEdit(object item);
     object GetModifiedItem();
}

public class DataModifierFactory
{
     public Func<IEnumerable<object>> GetData { get; set; }
     public Func<IEditorForm> EditorFormFactory { get; set; }
}

//in your code, set up how the types will get handled
//keep this registration of types and editor info on ObjectSelect form
Dictionary<Type,DataModifierFactory> myModifiers = new Dictionary<Type,DataModifierFactory>();

Func<IEnumerable<object>> intDataSource = ()=>{ return new int[] { 0,1,2,3 }; };
Func<IEditorForm> intEditorFormFactory = ()=>new IntEditorForm();
myModifiers.Add(typeof(int), new DataModifierFactory(){GetData=intDataSource,EditorFormFactory=intEditorFormFactory};

Func<IEnumerable<object>> stringDataSource = ()=>{ return new string[] { "A","B","C" }; };
Func<IEditorForm> stringDataFormFactory = ()=>new StringEditorForm();
myModifiers.Add(typeof(string), new DataModifierFactory(){GetData=stringDataSource,EditorFormFactory=stringDataFormFactor};


//On object select form
//this variable is set from above
Dictionary<Type,DataModifierFactory> m_DataModifierFactoryRegistry;
IEditorForm m_ItemEditorForm;

public void ModifyDataOfType<T>()
{
    DataModifierFactory factory = m_DataModifierFactoryRegistry[typeof(T)];
    myListOfData.Source = factory.GetData();
    m_ItemEditorForm = factory.EditorFormFactory();
}

public void OnSelectedItemChanged(object newItem)
{
    object oldItem = m_ItemEditorForm.GetModifiedItem();
    //save the old item, etc. Possibly another item on DataModiferFactory
    //then set up for the next
    m_ItemEditorForm.SetItemToEdit(newItem);
}
```

At any rate, that should give the basic idea. Rather than using Func, you could certainly have factories as interfaces etc. In WPF I know I'd try to use generics instead of object for item editor forms, etc. but I don't know how complex your scenario is.

Does this solve your problem?